# Set specific time to have Windows index my hard drive?

Tags: windows-7

Does anyone know if a particular piece of software that will enable me to control the time in which Windows 7 search feature indexes my hard drives?  It would be awesome to have it only index the drives (or turn on the index service) between a couple of hours each day.  It seems my drives want to index right at the worst possible moment when I am using them heavily.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to schedule the index without writing a script to stop and start the index. Fortunately, the script is quite basic.

Create 2 batch files:

**StopIndex.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
NET STOP "Windows Search"
EXIT
```

**StartIndex.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
NET START "Windows Search"
EXIT
```

Then go into your task scheduler and create a 2 separate tasks:

1. Start Index: point the action to the StartIndex.bat file
2. Stop Index: point the action to the StopIndex.bat file

Of Note: be sure to select the checkbox of "Run with highest privileges" under the General tab, otherwise the stopping and starting will fail.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem that when you stop windows search service, it starts after a while automaticaly

So i modified the scripts as follows

Start index

```
@ECHO OFF
sc config Wsearch start= delayed-auto
NET START "Windows Search"
EXIT
```

Stop Index

```
@ECHO OFF
sc config Wsearch start= disabled
NET STOP "Windows Search"
EXIT
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with stopping the windows search service is that it will not only stop indexing but also search queries will not be served either. I usually find it better to keep indexing running, but I set a low priority for the SearchIndexer.exe process from task manager (from normal->background).